# How can I extract a value from an html page in vbscript - I tried MSXML2.DOMDocument

Tags: html, vbscript, domdocument

Below is some code I tried to get the value from a node in webpage. But it fails when trying to set the objNode... any help gratefully appreciated.

```
Dim objHttp, sWebPage, objNode, objDoc

Set objDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
objDoc.Load "http://www.hl.co.uk/shares/shares-search-results/a/aveva-group-plc-ordinary-3.555p"

' objDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

' Find a particular element using XPath:
Set objNode = objDoc.selectSingleNode("span[@id='ls-bid-AVV-L']")
MsgBox objNode.getAttribute("value")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's very optimistic to expect an XML parser to handle **clean** HTML; for flawed HTML, you can forget it ([ref](http://www.glennslayden.com/code/html-xml-dom)).
2. You should never .load without checking for errors ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19195587/603855)). In your case, the .reason thrown is "The attribute 'property' on this element is not defined in the DTD/Schema."
3. You can switch off the validation with `objDoc.validateOnParse = False` and avoid problems with monster pages with `objDoc.async = False` (at least no "msxml3.dll: The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available." error).
4. To search for a span anywhere (without knowing its place in the hierarchy) you need "//span[@id='ls-bid-AVV-L']" instead of "span[@id='ls-bid-AVV-L']".
5. The span to find has no attribute named value; to get the "1,334.00p" you'd need to ask for `objNode.text`.
6. But all this is to no avail: The page is not even well-formed. The .parseError.reason is "End tag 'div' does not match the start tag 'input'.".

Answer (score 1):

Use the Internet Explorer COM object:

```
url = "http://www.hl.co.uk/shares/shares-search-results/a/aveva-group-plc-ordinary-3.555p"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate url
While ie.ReadyState <> 4
  WScript.Sleep 100
Wend

MsgBox ie.document.getElementById("ls-bid-AVV-L").innerText

ie.Quit
```