# extracting value from specific node in html using VBScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vbscript, domxpath

Is there any way to extract DomXPath of specific html elements using Vbscript in Internet Explorer???

```
 Sub WaitForLoad 'Sub to wait for browser to load
 Do While IE.Busy
   WScript.Sleep 10
 Loop   
End Sub

Dim IE
Dim example1
Dim example2

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True 
    IE.navigate "http://www.lotteimall.com/goods/viewGoodsDetail.lotte?goods_no=12570568"
    WaitForLoad 

Set objRoot = ie.document

MsgBox objRoot.getElementById("win10").name


Dim vXPath : vXPath = "//*[@id='win10']"

Set example1 = objRoot.selectSingleNode(vXPath) 'this works for xml
Set example2 = objRoot.getElemetByXPath(vXPath) 'this works in javascript

'none of these works in IE html
```

there is no DomXPath function like 'getElemetByXPath' in IE document object, I couldn't still proper method that returns DomXPath.

As for the javascript,

```
    function XPath(elm) {
           for (segs = []; elm && elm.nodeType == 1; elm = elm.parentNode) {
             if (elm.hasAttribute('id')) {
               segs.unshift('id("' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '")')
               return segs.join('/')
             }
             else if (elm.hasAttribute('class'))
               segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@class="' + elm.getAttribute('class') + '"]')
             else {
               for (i = 1, sib = elm.previousSibling; sib; sib = sib.previousSibling)
                 if (sib.localName == elm.localName) i++
               segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[' + i + ']')
             }
           }
           return segs.length ? '/' + segs.join('/') : null
    }
    var result = windows.document.evaluate("//div[@class='division_product_tab']//img", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

    var node, nodes = []
    while (node = result.iterateNext())
      nodes.push(XPath(node));

    console.log(nodes);
```

This returns object-specific of DomXpath. In this case, "//div[@class='division_product_tab']//img" which is img object. but this only work in Dev Tool.

I hope there might be solution for this

Comment: Did you try this code? `objRoot.getElemetByXPath(vXPath)` isn't going to work in anything, think you mean `getElementByXPath()`. Plus it is a helper function that makes use of [`document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#document.evaluate) it isn't part of vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: yeap, it does not, I've been looking for the method like those, which are available in VBScript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extract a value from an html page in vbscript - I tried MSXML2.DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442645/how-can-i-extract-a-value-from-an-html-page-in-vbscript-i-tried-msxml2-domdocu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [to use CSS Selectors](https://flukeout.github.io/):

```vb
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With oIE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.lotteimall.com/goods/viewGoodsDetail.lotte?goods_no=12570568"
    Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
        WScript.Sleep 10
    Loop
    Do While .Document.readyState <> "complete"
        WScript.Sleep 10
    Loop
    Set oNode = .Document.querySelector("div.division_product_tab img")
    MsgBox oNode.src
End With
```

`.querySelector()` returns a first node, and `.querySelectorAll()` returns a collection of nodes.

Comment: Tnx, it seems it's the only solution for now :)