# Search for a specific value in XML and Modify through VBS

Tags: xml, vbscript

I was having a hard time to think of a way how to find a specific value and modify if found in an XML file. So, I began googling and found an article. However, I can't seem to understand the code that was used as a solution to their problem. I also tried modifying the code but unfortunately I could not make it worked.

```
<Configuration>
<Add SourcePath="\\sample" ApplicationEdition="32">
    <Product ID="SampleProductID">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
```

I need to modify the content of this value `<Add SourcePath=` I've tried several times and no luck writing a vbscript to change its value. I would appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the VBScript you are stuck with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Publish complete/valid XML (cf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194544/selectsinglenode-using-vbscript))
2. Show the code you have problems with
3. Link to your sources
4. Don't use antique tools (XMLDOM vs. [msxml2.domdocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
5. Avoid spurious () in Sub call
6. Use basic error handling (cf 1)
7. Use specific/strict XPath expressions (no // without reason)
8. Don't use `Set x = Nothing` [just for fun](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing.aspx)

Demo:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oXDoc  : Set oXDoc = CreateObject( "Msxml2.DOMDocument" )
oXDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
oXDoc.async = False
oXDoc.load "..\data\31677574.xml"

If 0 = oXDoc.ParseError Then
   WScript.Echo oXDoc.documentElement.xml
   Dim sXPath : sXPath    = "/Configuration/Add"
   Dim ndFnd  : Set ndFnd = oXDoc.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
   If Not ndFnd Is Nothing Then
      ndFnd.getAttributeNode("SourcePath").value = "SomeOtherValue"
      WScript.Echo "----------------", vbCrLf & oXDoc.documentElement.xml
   Else
      WScript.Echo sXPath, "- not found"
   End If
Else
   WScript.Echo oXDoc.ParseError.Reason
End If
```

output:

```
cscript 31677574-2.vbs
<Configuration>
        <Add SourcePath="\\sample" ApplicationEdition="32">
                <Product ID="SampleProductID">
                        <Language ID="en-us"/>
                        <Language ID="en-us"/>
                </Product>
        </Add>
</Configuration>
----------------
<Configuration>
        <Add SourcePath="SomeOtherValue" ApplicationEdition="32">
                <Product ID="SampleProductID">
                        <Language ID="en-us"/>
                        <Language ID="en-us"/>
                </Product>
        </Add>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: This was helpful, thanks for this script is now working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load("T.xml")
Set objAdd = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//Configuration/Add")
objAdd.Attributes.getNamedItem("SourcePath").Text = "Test"
xmlDoc.Save "T.xml"
Set objAdd = Nothing
Set xmlDoc = Nothing
```

I recommend you view these pages

1. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.02.heyscriptingguy.aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx