# Unable to use the values in vbscript (for file copy) fetched from an XML file

Tags: vbscript

What we are trying to achieve: To read directory paths from an XML file and perform a copy and paste operation. The script works if we remove the last line: `fso.CopyFolder Directory, t`. But it fails when we keep this line. The script is able to read the values from the XML file.

> Error occurs at line no: 19

i.e.: For each child in `objRoot.childNodes`, saying “Object Required”

```
Option Explicit
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim fso, objDoc, objRoot, child, s, t, WshShell, filesys, ObjShell,objDox

Set objDoc = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
objDoc.Async = False
objDoc.Load "location.xml"
objDoc.validateOnParse=False
Set objRoot = objDoc.documentElement
Dim CurrentDirectory, Directory
    CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
For Each child in objRoot.childNodes
   s = child.getAttribute("Source")
   t = child.getAttribute("Destination")
   Directory = CurrentDirectory & "\" & s
Next

fso.CopyFolder Directory, t
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19195587/603855

Comment: Can you post your XML file? Does it have a root node? `documentElement` will return the root node, and if you only have a list of nodes you will get this error.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<copy>
      <Directory Source="alpha" Destination="C:\Program Files\Jira\" />
      <Directory Source="Beta" Destination="C:\Program Files\Jira\" />
    
</copy>

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing

```
fso.CopyFolder Directory, t
```

to

```
fso.CopyFolder Directory, t & "\"
```

because when copying or moving to a folder you have to end the destination folder with a "\"